# Merging two patches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, patch

I have two patches that I'd like to merge in mercurial. Sadly, I deleted the branch from which I exported these patches. Can you guys please suggest a way to merge the two patches?

I am using Mercurial 2.0.2 on a ubuntu 12.04 box.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing a separate commit for each patch?

Comment: Nothing is stopping me, but, I wish to submit that patch to an open source project, so I thought, it would be clean to send just one patch instead of a lot of them.

Answer (score 5):

If you have MQ enabled, and assuming you start with an empty patch queue:

```
> hg qimport patch1        # Import & apply the first patch into a patch queue
> hg qimport patch2        # Import & apply the second patch into a patch queue
> hg qpop;                 # Pop the second patch (unapply)
> hg qfold patch2          # Fold the second patch into the first (result is called 'patch1')
> hg qexport > new_merged_patch
```

You can then either:

```
> hg qfinish -a            # Convert the currently applied patches (e.g. patch1) to changesets)
```

or:

```
> hg qpop                  # Pop the merged patch
> hg qdel patch1           # Delete it from the queue
```

To be honest, using MQ for this is overkill, but it's a useful extension to know.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the patches as patch files you can just apply them on top of each other and generate a patch based on the result:

```
$ patch -p0 < patch1
$ patch -p0 < patch2
$ hg diff > cumulative.patch
```

The patch level, `-p0`, may be different depending on how your patches are structured.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is 'cumulative.patch' I copy and pasted the hg diff > {added name}, but didn't add the .patch as I assumed that an indicator not to be taken literally.

Comment: `cumulative.patch` is just the merging of `patch1` and `patch2`. You could also call it `merged.patch` or whatever you want. I hope that answers your question.